# Why are combinations used in the expansion of $(a + b)^4$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The difference between Permutation and Combination is that in Permutation order matters, Combination order doesn't matter.

So in $ABC, ACB$, the permutation is $2$, and combination is $1$.

But, to expand $(a+b)^4$, the $(a^3)b$ term's coefficient is $4\choose {1}$$  = 4$ ways of getting three $a$'s and $1$ $b$ multiplied together,

namely:

$aaab,  aaba,  abaa,   baaa$. But that's the same combination, shouldn't it (combination) equal to 1? Why 4?

$4\choose 1$$ = \frac{4!}{(1!) \cdot (3!)} = 4$

That's permutation isn't it?

I understand that adding the $(a^3)b$s there are $4$ altogether, but why that's combination?

I'm really confused.

Comment: I believe the confusion lies in the fact that you are not choosing from $a$ and $b$ but rather $4\choose 1$ you are choosing a single element out of $\{A,B,C,D\}$ and you are calculating how many out of $4!$ possible permutations of that set is the element you chose first?.

Answer (score 1):

There are e.g. $5C2=10$ ways to select $2$ out of $5$:

- $XXOOO$
- $XOXOO$
- $XOOXO$
- $\cdots$
- $OOOXX$

Here the order of selecting does not matter and we are dealing with combinations.

There are $5P2=20$ ways to select $2$ out of $5$ if order matters:

- $X_1X_2OOO$
- $X_2X_1OOO$
- $X_1OX_2OO$
- $X_2OX_1OO$
- $\cdots$
- $OOOX_1X_2$
- $OOOX_2X_1$

Here the order of selecting matters and we are dealing with permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the sequence length $n$ of 0s and 1s. You have a total of $(1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$, so $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to select $k$ different positions in the sequence. All these positions are different (indices),  but the order of choice is not important. So $\binom{4}{1}$ is the number of ways to select a position for $a: 1, 2, 3, 4$, which are different.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand
$$(a + b)^4 = (a + b)(a + b)(a + b)(a + b)$$
each term is determined by selecting either an $a$ or a $b$ from each of the four factors.  For instance, if you choose an $a$ from the first three factors and a $b$ from the fourth factor, you obtain $aaab = a^3b$.  The coefficient of $\binom{4}{1}$ for $a^3b$ in the binomial expansion
$$(a + b)^4 = \binom{4}{0}a^4b^0 + \binom{4}{1}a^3b^1 + \binom{4}{2}a^2b^2 + \binom{4}{3}a^1b^3 + \binom{4}{4}a^0b^4$$
represents the number of ways a $b$ can be selected from exactly one of the four factors.  We use combinations in the binomial expansion since we are selecting the subset of factors from which a $b$ is drawn.